# Diferença de impedância objeto-relacional

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, orm, modelo-relacional

Questionamento básico sobre [object-relational impedance mismatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch), um tópico com o qual tenho pouca experiência.

1. **Ela realmente existe?** *(Decerto que sim; [Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/OrmHate.html) e [Ted Neward](http://blog.codinghorror.com/object-relational-mapping-is-the-vietnam-of-computer-science/) já falaram sobre o problema, mas será que ela realmente ocorre em todas as situações envolvendo objetos e banco de dados relacional?)*
2. **Se sim, em quais situações costuma ocorrer?** *(Por exemplo, é um problema específico de sistemas em que o modelo de domínio guia o design do banco e não o contrário?)*
3. **De que formas tem sido solucionada?** *(Existem diferentes "sabores" de ORM, bem como soluções baseadas em retirar o "O" ou o "R" da equação)*
4. **Quais as limitações dessas soluções?**

Comment: Os dois artigos citados na pergunta apresentam eles próprios respostas ótimas (respostas muito muito boas mesmo!) para esta pergunta. E são textos longos demais e em alguns momentos opinativos demais para o formato do SO. Qual problema exatamente você propõe resolvermos aqui? Pode fazer uma pergunta mais objetiva?

Comment: Lembrando: "Você deve fazer apenas perguntas práticas, que admitam respostas com base em problemas reais que tiver. Perguntas extensas e abertas diminuem a utilidade de nosso site e retiram outras perguntas da página inicial." http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @Caffé Eu queria chegar a uma resposta não-opinativa sobre o problema, se isso for possível. Se isso não for possível devido a uma gama muito ampla de cenários, eu gostaria de uma resposta dividida por cenário, que cubra pelo menos casos considerados principais ou mais comuns. Se for o caso eu posso reformular a pergunta.

Comment: @Caffé Também gostaria que, dado um cenário e a solução adotada (ou as soluções) para resolver o problema da impedância, fossem explicadas de maneira didática as suas limitações, para dar uma base de compreensão para o iniciante no tema de forma a ser capaz de avaliar, com relativa propriedade, uma nova solução de impedância com a qual se depare (o que na maioria dos casos será alguma forma de ORM ou DBMS não-relacional). Mesmo que as respostas variem com as experiências individuais, o SO traz a vantagem de fornecer a avaliação das melhores respostas e portanto um norte para o iniciante.

Answer (score 1):

Talvez minha resposta seja vaga, mas se formos analisar, a pergunta foi muito ampla e eu não possuo reputação para comentar.

Basta você ver a situação da seguinte forma, a proposta das ORM's é uma mentira. É a mesma coisa de dizer que você vai misturar água e óleo. Se você precisa apenas de um liquido qualquer a mistura serve, mas se você precisa dar ênfase em algum dos dois lados, você vai ter que abrir mão do outro.

O que quero dizer é, objetos são formados por duas coisas, obrigatoriamente: dados e comportamento, ou seja, uma classe que não possui métodos ou funções, não é um objeto. É apenas uma "Estrutura de Dados" ou Data Structure.

Como você representaria encapsulamento em uma tabela de banco de dados? ou herança? não tem como embutir comportamento em uma tabela de banco de dados da mesma forma que você faz com um objeto, as duas coisas de fato não combinam.

Mas é possível sim, extrair parte das duas coisas e formar estruturas de dados bem parecidas e que provavelmente vão atender suas necessidades, tudo é uma questão de julgamento. Não me recordo de passar por alguma situação onde "Diferença de Impedância" tenha sido um problema surpresa, o problema existe sim, a gente aprende a conviver com ele.

Edit:

A discussão nos comentários me fez pensar em uma possível solução.

Neste link : http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2013/10/01/Dance-You-Imps.html o [Uncle Bob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Cecil_Martin) descreve como "Tabelas" não são "Objetos de Negócio" e sim "Estruturas de Dados" (ou classes sem método/funções) das quais os **verdadeiros objetos de negócio** usam como recurso.

Uma forma de evitar "diferença de impedância" é segregar o "objeto relacional" do objeto de negócio. Veja um exemplo:

Objeto de Negócio:

```
public class Carro
{
    public abstract string Placa { get; set; }

    public bool PlacaEhValida()
    {
        return this.Placa.Length == 7;
    }
}
```

Objeto Relacional:

```
public class CarroORM : Carro
{
    [ColumnName("plate_number")]
    public override string Placa { get; set; }
}
```

Desta maneira você evita a tentação de achar que o objeto relacional é de fato um objeto e passa à usá-lo de forma mais similar a uma tabela do banco de dados.

Comment: O motivo é o hint do botão de downvote: "esta resposta não é útil". Ela não responde a pergunta, é baseada somente em opinião, não apresenta evidências, e além de tudo é prejudicial ao SO pois atrai um tipo de discussão inadequado aos objetivos do portal. Se você considera vaga sua resposta, mesmo que seja pelo motivo de a pergunta ser muito ampla, considere não publicá-la.

Comment: @Caffé concordo com você, mas acredito que para uma pergunta como esta, fica difícil responder explicitamente outra coisa, eu não tenho pontos o suficiente para comentar, portanto decidi fazer uma resposta propriamente dita. Você mesmo deu dicas para o usuário que fez a pergunta, e eu trabalhei em cima justamente de dar os exemplos que ele queria, nem sempre existe material para esse tipo de dúvida, na minha opinião, cabe a ele julgar.

Comment: O AP também pode julgar. Ele pode up-votar questão (como toda a comunidade) além de poder marcá-la como sendo a resposta escolhida.

Comment: Na verdade o posicionamento dessa resposta é parecido com o do [Robert "Uncle Bob" Martin](http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2013/10/01/Dance-You-Imps.html) a respeito do tema. A minha pergunta então seria, "extrair parte das duas coisas e formar estruturas de dados bem parecidas e que provavelmente vão atender suas necessidades" não significa justamente fazer mapeamento objeto-relacional, ou pelo menos uma forma específica do mesmo?

Comment: @Piovezan Esta resposta não é em absolutamente nada parecida com o posicionamento do Uncle Bob!

Comment: @Piovezan Exatamente, mas o problema é o nome "objeto-relacional". Não acredito na existência de tal coisa, mas existe um limite até onde podemos chegar e ele definitivamente é alcançável (como você disse, uma forma específica). O que tenho feito é desacoplado os objetos utilizados para fazer esse relacionamento das minhas entidades em si. Desta forma os objetos de banco (ou mapeamentos) possuem apenas dados e minhas entidades possuem dados e comportamento, essa separação permite que mudanças feitas no objeto de banco não atinja minha entidade. Entende?

Comment: @Caffé Tem certeza? http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2013/10/01/Dance-You-Imps.html

Comment: Tenho certeza absoluta. Estudei bastante este artigo. Ele diz, por exemplo, que se você acha que "a proposta das ORM's é uma mentira", você não entendeu a proposta.

Comment: @Caffé Desculpe, mas não encontrei essa afirmação no artigo. Por outro lado encontrei _"You can't store behavior in a database. And that means you can't store objects in a database. And that means there's no Object to Relational mapping"_, que no meu entender é bem parecido com parte do conteúdo da resposta, a saber: _"não tem como embutir comportamento em uma tabela de banco de dados da mesma forma que você faz com um objeto, as duas coisas de fato não combinam."_

Comment: @Piovezan Um bom artigo é feito para ser assimilado em seu todo, não para ser referenciado por frases isoladas. E aqui estou eu em uma discussão que eu próprio anunciei que seria infrutífera no SO. Como eu previ, nada foi agregado além dos artigos (pelo contrário, pode servir bem para distorcê-los).

Comment: @BrenoSarkis O código que você postou na sua edição pode ser considerado um esboço (*unimportant aside comment removed*) das soluções de ORM usadas por aí.

Comment: @Caffé Peço desculpas se não entendi o artigo, estou perguntando sobre o conteúdo que você extraiu dele justamente para me ajudar a entender o que o artigo diz.

Comment: @Piovezan Eu não extraí nenhum conteúdo do artigo. A parte entre aspas foi copiada da pergunta e a parte seguinte é uma das idéias passadas pelo artigo, notavelmente pela sua conclusão que diz, dentre outras coisas, para você usar ORM à vontade desde que você não o confunda com um mapeamento entre seus objetos negócio e o banco de dados.

Comment: @Caffé "Extraiu conteúdo" é um modo de dizer. Perguntava sobre a informação que você apreendeu do artigo. Acho que entendi o motivo pelo qual você diz que as conclusões são diferentes. A resposta sugere um design específico de objetos para satisfazer a diferença de impedância enquanto o artigo aprova qualquer ferramenta de ORM desde que esteja claro no momento do design que a ferramenta não objetiva vincular estado relacional a objetos com comportamento, apenas migrar estados. Para mim isso é curioso porque eu achava que projetar assim geraria dif. de impedância por si só. Então nem sempre?

Comment: @Piovezan Você acaba de apresentar uma pergunta bem bacana. Sim isso tende a gerar uma diferença de impedância. O Uncle Bob neste artigo faz parecer que não está nem aí pra isso (ele até tira onda de salvarmos dados em disco). Ele é um artista e um filósofo indispensável para o desenv. da nossa área, mas p/ responder esta sua última pergunta eu recomendo o artigo do Fowler que você citou na perg. original. Lá ele diz, dentre outras coisas, que se você vai usar um banco pode sim perfeitamente considerar isso no design da solução (sendo que "considerar no design" é diferente de "guiar o design")